# Is PCI - DSS required to store only card number

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, payment-gateway

We need to save the **credit card number** in our database , but not the cvv.
Should we be **PCI - DSS** compliant for this or some security measures is enough.
After the save we will use that to call stripe for payment.

So should we go ahead with PCI - DSS compliance?

Comment: Uh, [Stripe allows for tokenized cards](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens), which is what you should be using.  Attach it to a `Customer` object if you really need to reuse it.  If you can get the tokenization to happen client-side, PCI-DSS pretty much completely goes away.  As near as I know, tokens are specific to your merchant id, so there's no issue around leaking them - but I could very well be wrong about that last bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - if you store, process or transmit cardholder data you need to comply with PCI DSS.

I’d really question your decision to store the 16-digit PAN (credit card number) in the database - Stripe has some great options that may enable you not to do this, criminals love databases containing cardholder data.

Comment: Yeah I know the security risk. But the client wants this.